# Extend AD accounts for 6 months in PowerShell via Text file to output new user expiry date into CSV

Tags: powershell, automation, export-to-csv, extend

I have and little command that will extend AD accounts for 6 months (define the date) for each user in a text file:

`Get-Content C:\adextensions.txt | Set-ADAccountExpiration -DateTime "09/16/2023"`

I was wondering if someone could assist me in creating a script that would automatically set expiry date 6 months from the current date when the command is executed.

I know you could set something like this:

`$New_Expiry_Date = [datetime]::Now.addmonths(6)`

Something like this:

```
$New_Expiry_Date = [datetime]::Now.addmonths(6)

Get-Content C:\adextensions.txt | Set-ADAccountExpiration -DateTime $New_Expiry_Date
```

Also if possible could the results of each user new account expiry date be outputted to a CSV file showing username and expiry date.

I am very basic learner at PowerShell.

**UPDATE 1**

@Theo I ran your code.

Added Get Credential code:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

Set-ADAccountExpiration -Credential $cred
```

```
$New_Expiry_Date = (get-Date).AddMonths(6).Date  # .Date sets this to midnight
$cred = Get-Credential

# assuming the file holds the SamAccountNames of the users each on its own line
# (or the users DistinguishedName, the SID or the object GUID)
$result = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\adextensions.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADAccountExpiration -Credential $cred -Identity $_ -DateTime $New_Expiry_Date
    # output an object to collect in variable $result
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        User = $_
        AccountExpires = $New_Expiry_Date
    }
}

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\AccountExpiryDates.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

When I ran the code I got this error message

Seems like it states I don't have the permission to execute the script.

I do get prompted to enter a username and password before the script run, my AD account is domain admin account.

```
PS C:\Users\Me> $New_Expiry_Date = (get-Date).AddMonths(6).Date  # .Date sets this to midnight
$cred = Get-Credential

# assuming the file holds the SamAccountNames of the users each on its own line
# (or the users DistinguishedName, the SID or the object GUID)
$result = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\adextensions.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADAccountExpiration -Credential $cred -Identity $_ -DateTime $New_Expiry_Date
    # output an object to collect in variable $result
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        User = $_
        AccountExpires = $New_Expiry_Date
    }
}

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\AccountExpiryDates.csv' -NoTypeInformation
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Set-ADAccountExpiration : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation
At line:7 char:5
+     Set-ADAccountExpiration -Credential $cred -Identity $_ -DateTime $New_Expiry ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (TestUser:ADAccount) [Set-ADAccountExpiration], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountExpiration
```

Also when I run the original script you provided me (whilst running Windows  PowerShell ISE as Administrator) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me, but if you want output to say a CSV file, you need to use a loop.

```
$New_Expiry_Date = (get-Date).AddMonths(6).Date  # .Date sets this to midnight

# assuming the file holds the SamAccountNames of the users each on its own line
# (or the users DistinguishedName, the SID or the object GUID)
$result = Get-Content -Path 'C:\adextensions.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $_ -DateTime $New_Expiry_Date
    # output an object to collect in variable $result
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        User = $_
        AccountExpires = $New_Expiry_Date
    }
}

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\AccountExpiryDates.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>You may need to add admin credentials using the `-Credential` parameter on the `Set-ADAccountExpiration` cmdlet</sup>

Comment: Thanks again @Theo (will try your script next week) also when executing scripts I open PS ISE as 'Run as Administrator" usually doesn't require me to define admin details within the script (I guess I am being lazy), When using the -credential parameter is it possible to request the user who is executing the script to enter admin username and password? As looking on google you can define it using Get-Credential.

Comment: @S.Mahmood Yes, just use `$cred = Get-Credential` to ask for a user name and password. Then use that on `Set-ADAccountExpiration -Credential $cred ...`

Comment: Theo please see my update. Seems like there is permission issue (unless I amended the script you provided incorrectly) in short the script does work.